# Mouseover and mouseout for rectangle are not fired correctly in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map, and I draw a rectangle on it. Here is what I want: whenever my mouse enter that rectangle, open an infowindow, when my mouse leave, close the infowindow.

I have successfully created a map and drawn a rectangle. Here is my code:

```
var map;
function initialize() {

    // Init map
    var mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: ***, lng: *** },
        zoom: 13,
        draggable: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
        drawGrid();
    });

} // end initialize

function drawGrid() {
    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        map: map,
        bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw1, ne1) //sw1 and ne1 is my variable
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Hello",
        position: rectangle.getBounds().getCenter()
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'mouseover', function () {
        infowindow.open(map);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'mouseout', function () {
        infowindow.close();
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

You can see the result below. The rectangle is the black one.
[image: My result]

Now, the problems are:

1. `Mouseover` event is fired only when I let my mouse follow the green arrows.
2. `Mouseout` event is fired only when my mouse follow the green arrows (yes, from out to in, not in to out as expected), and it's fired **twice**.

Why do I encounter those problems? What did I do wrong? How to solve this problem? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: try "mouseenter" and "mouseleave"

Comment: Is this in Firefox 39.0?  [Your code as posted (but fixed missing variables with ones I made up) works for me in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/nsdj6yu5/1/)

Comment: @geocodezip: yes! It works fine with Chrome. What's problem with Firefox 39.0?

Comment: @Scelesto: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events are not available for rectangle events. Please check the document :)

Comment: See [Issue 8278 (among others) in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8278)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a change to the way Firefox 39.0 handles mouse events.  See [issue 8278 in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8278)

```
Project Member #4 enoch...@google.com
Thanks for reporting this issue. Indeed, it appears that Firefox 39 has made changes to its mouse event, which is causing the API to behave incorrectly.
Status: Accepted 
Owner: enoch...@google.com 
Labels: Internal-20820906
```

Note that users have reported that v=3 (the release version) is working correctly and this issue only appears in v=3.exp (the "experimental" version).